# Binding Observable Collection to a GridView

Tags: c#, .net, windows-store-apps

```
<GridView  SelectionMode="None" x:Name="InvoiceContainer" CanReorderItems="True" 
 ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate2}" ItemsSource="{Binding SecondCollection}"
/>
```

I'm Using windows Store apps.
I have used an observable collection to bind data to the grid view. I need to bind all items in reverse order.

ex item 3, item 2, item 1 instead of item 1, item 2, item 3

Comment: what is your ItemTemplate2

Comment: Template is for gridViewItems.... for the display.. ItemsSource is for binding data..

Answer (score 0):

You will need to sort the collection before binding. You can use LINQ to create a newly ordered collection. Assuming your data items have a "Name" element you want to sort on you can do the following:

```
data = new ObservableCollection<DataItem>(data.[OrderByDescending][1](d => d.Name));
```

It's not built-in, but there are extended versions of CollectionViewSource which support sorting. I can't vouch for any specifically, but a [quick search for CollectionViewSource Sort WinRT](http://www.bing.com/search?q=collectionviewsource%20sort%20winrt&qs=n&form=QBRE&pq=collectionviewsource%20sort%20winrt&sc=0-26&sp=-1&sk=&cvid=fab508fd9e3c47ca85c72383be0b8508) found several that look promising.